# Path Manipulation Vulnerability

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, vulnerability, source-code, code-review

Currently I am working in code review process. 
I have few doubts regrading Path Manipulation Vulnerability.
Some portion of the Path is already hard coded and with extension

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            String fname=args[0];
        fname="C:\\Users\\kutrivedi\\Desktop\\Ref\\"+fname+".txt";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.print(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Questions:

1) Exploitation is Possible ?

2) If yes than How attacker exploit that functionality ?

3) Is there any payload to go to the back directory when directory wrote by developer ?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: With the example that you post, the response is yes, if you give value to the variable fname = "../../../pepe/Desktop/Ref/somefile.txt" then your path will be compromise. There is a lot of examples of how to mitigate and program correctly in order to avoid these issues

Comment: @camp0 Thanks for your response can you please elaborate your answer for better understanding

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to exploit this code?

Yes.

> How can an attacker exploit this?

Path Traversal Vulnerabilities allow an attacker to choose a file that is not intended by the developer.

For example, your program has the path `"C:\\Users\\kutrivedi\\Desktop\\Ref\\" + input + ".txt"` hardcoded. If I entered `foo` as input, then the resulting file would be `C:\\Users\\kutrivedi\\Desktop\\Ref\\foo.txt`.

Of course, I could add more than just one word, such as `foo\\bar`, which would result in the following file being read instead: `C:\\Users\\kutrivedi\\Desktop\\Ref\\foo\\bar.txt`

So just by adding `\\`, I can traverse deeper into the file structure.

> Can an attacker traverse the file system up?

I can do that too, with the pseudo-directory `..`. Every directory has a pseudo-entry called `..`, which points to the parent. As such, if I enter `..\\foo`, then the following path is created `C:\\Users\\kutrivedi\\Desktop\\Ref\\..\\foo.txt`, which will be resolved to `C:\\Users\\kutrivedi\\Desktop\\foo.txt`.

For example, if my payload is `..\\..\\..\\..\\foo`, then I would now read `C:\\foo.txt`.

I could go further and print arbitrary files, as long as they had a `.txt` extension. Since this code was presumably written in Java, and Java does not terminate strings with a `\0` character, there is no easy way to terminate the string earlier to skip the extension.

If, however, your programming language was built on null-terminating strings, my payload could read arbitrary files too, as long as the process had permission to read them:

`..\\..\\..\\..\\Windows\\System32\\config\\SAM\0` will result in `C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\SAM`.

> How can this be fixed?

The easiest way is to use a library or built-in framework, which deals with paths. Most libraries have checks to see if something is inside or outside a directory structure, so you can use those checks to see if the payload you are getting is trying to access a file it shouldn't.